# Is Stack Overflow China or the USSR?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

Seeing that with the "[new rules](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/13/changes-to-stack-exchange/)" certain sub communities could theoretically splinter off SO, like say a Python or a PHP community, will this be allowed and supported?

Comment: What new rules? You mean on StackExchange?

Comment: See proposal phase in the link

Comment: More like the Balkan: we'll have a nasty war and everyone goes their seperate ways. Though look what happened with Europe as a whole. Two World Wars and still trying to form one big happy family

Comment: Do you mean supported like speech recognition or supported like beer consumption?

Answer (score 7):

I have seen some (small) splinters; there is an iPhone SE for example. Personally, I **hugely** value the cross-fertilisation of ideas on Stack Overflow, so I **really** don't want that to happen.

That is also one of the things I find so objectionable about the iPhone SDK, btw. Seriously? The actual released API is under NDA? Get behind me, Apple! (throws salt, etc.).

I think the SE rules are more for your "fly fishing" site. So I **don't** see this as a threat to Stack Overflow. Jeff wants the site to thrive, too ;-p

Comment: Sometimes I think there's just too much clutter on the front page. 90% of the questions there are not answerable for me, despite my tag filters. Therefore I'd think sub-communities _might_ be good. (A better system to show me appropriate questions is definitely better.)

Answer (score 4):

If that is the case then every single programming could have a separate site. Existing SO helps me to learn A-Z in what ever language. "Get into SO, you will get answer for all the question regardless of languages". I say this statement to all my colleagues. I feel that the uniqueness of SO will lost.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure such a thing will be allowed by our Dear Leader. Stack Overflow is the crown jewel in the Stack Overflow LLC crown; if we start to splinter the site it's going to turn into a mess and could be a really bad thing for us as a community as well.

I'm not exactly sure where things are going with this whole Stack Exchange 2.0, but one thing I wouldn't want to see is having the community torn apart by it.

Answer (score 1):

The "new rules" would allow it as long as there is enough community support to start a region/language/country specific site.

Comment: Support has to come not only from the community, but from Stack Overflow LLC as well. That makes things trickier for such a site.